# rake aborted! undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

rake solr:start throws this error

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Somewhere along the line the closed? method is being called on an object that is nil. If you post the whole stack trace we can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: Can you put the output of same command with --trace ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have google around and got frustrated. I found the answer

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2708

you have to go in /lib/ruby/1.8/net

and download the patch and add that additional check into http.rb and you are done

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/attachments/download/835

Thanks everyone

Comment: @vishB sorry but the links I added was in 2010 and now those are outdated.

Answer (score 0):

One simple answer is that you may have not started your sunspot solr. Try running

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

Another possible answer is related to ipv4 vs ipv6. Check out this thread for more info:
[Solr / Sunspot / Rails 3 error: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985617/solr-sunspot-rails-3-error-undefined-method-closed-for-nilnilclass)