# Solr / Sunspot / Rails 3 error: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I have this model:

```
class Book < Item
  validates :isbn, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  has_many  :book_chapters
  has_many  :chapters,  :through => :book_chapters

  searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do
      text :title
  end
end
```

And then I have this controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def index

      @search = Book.search do
        fulltext params[:search]
      end
      @books = @search.results

      [... normal rest of code ...]
    end
end
```

The field "title" is inherited from the more generic Item model. And when the Home controller tries to perform the search, I get this error:

> NoMethodError in HomeController#index
>
> undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass

There is also this additional warning in the log:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from /Users/xxx/Sites/zigzag/app/models/book.rb:7)

Which refers to the line:

> searchable :auto_index => true, :auto_remove => true do

in book.rb

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? In other similar posts on stack overflow it seems people forgot to turn on the sunspot server. But I'm running it, and its running fine. I can navigate the Solr Admin just fine. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong, this is best approached as a bug report for Sunspot. Try their mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-sunspot — you should also try to get a more complete stack trace for the `undefined method closed?` error. Finally, try updating to the latest source in git to see if the error has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm running this app on a Mac OS Lion 10.7.2. The issue was that the rails app was not indeed connected within the sunspot server. But the reason isn't because the sunspot server was missing. It was because rails was using IPv4 addresses while sunspot was expecting IPv6 addresses. The first part of the fix was to change the sunspot.yml config file so that the hostname is 127.0.0.1 and not 'localhost.' Then, in /etc/hosts, comment out the following lines:

```
#::1            localhost 
#fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

So that 'localhost' only maps to 127.0.0.1 (which is specified elsewhere in /etc/hosts/). That's it!

Comment: Open the Terminal all, and type "cd /etc/hosts"

Answer (score 0):

One simple answer is that you may have not started your sunspot solr. Try running this rake command:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```